# Angularjs checkbox initialization issue using json object

Tags: angularjs

So i have a checkbox page barely working, the issue is when i first start this page, the checkbox is not checked, even though i try to initialize it from backend node server. No error in browser debugger though.

---

in the server mye,

```
app.get('/2getMyDiagValue', function(req, res)
{
    console.log("get my diag");

    var formDataArray = { "formDataObjects": [
        {"flagName":"myStuff1", "flagVal":0},
        {"flagName":"myStuff2",   "flagVal":1}
    ]};

    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.send(formDataArray);
});
app.post('/2setMyDiagValue', function(req, res)
{
    ......
}
```

---

in the client mye,

```
app.controller('myDiagController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, QueryMyService) {
    $scope.message = 'SID Diagnostics';

    // using http.get() to get existing my setting from server mye
    QueryMyService.getInfoFromUrl7('/2getMyDiagValue').then(function(result) {
        $scope.formData = result.formDataObjects;
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error");
    } );

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        console.log("posting form data ...");
        $http.post("/2setMyDiagValue", 
                   JSON.stringify($scope.formData)).success(function(){} );
    };

});

app.factory('QueryMyService', function($http, $q, $location) {

    var factory = {};
        var browserProtocol = 'http';
        var port = ':1234';
        var address = 'localhost';
        var server = browserProtocol + '://' + address;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     factory.getInfoFromUrl7 = function(myUrl) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(myUrl).success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(){
            deferred.reject();
        }); 

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    return factory;
}
```

---

checkbox webpage itself

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="myDiagController">
    <div class="control-group" style="color:black">
        <label>My Checkbox</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="checbox-inline" >
                <input class="big-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.myStuff1" 
                   ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="formData.myStuff1 == 1">
                       <h4>Message 1</h4>
                <input class="big-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.myStuff2" 
                   ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="formData.myStuff2 == 1">
                       <h4>Message 2</h4>
            </label>
        </div>

    <br>
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit">

</form>
```

i did try to modify ng-checked like this and the checkbox did show checked.
    ng-checked="true"

Comment: i feel it's the json object issue, any suggestions pls ?

Comment: `ng-checked` doesn't work with `ng-model`. Not really clear how the form is supposed to work. `myStuff1` and `myStuff2` aren't properties of `formData` they are values of properties of objects within array `formData`

Comment: also note no need to stringify data for `$http.post` that is done internally, just pass in object

Comment: When i write <input class="big-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.myStuff2" 
                   ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="true">, the checkbox is checked when i open the page for the 1st time, so ng-checked shoulb ebe able to work with ng-model

Comment: as to "myStuff1 and myStuff2 aren't properties of formData", what' the correct way to write them pls ?

Comment: is that data supposed to determine if checkboxes are checked or not when it loads? You still didn't answer expected behavior based on data. Each object is one checkbox? One object only is sleected? Not clear whay data is array and form isn't an `ng-repeat` or if it needs to be

Comment: Remember that code that isn't working isn't a good substitute for a proper , detailed explanation of what the code should do

Comment: sorry replying late, for this test code, node.js suppose to return 1 for one of the checkbox, when i open this page, the controller will call 2getMyDiagValue to get this 1, then display this checkbox to be checked. Basically i'm trying to do initialization based on the value from web server backend.

Answer (score 0):

well, just used "res.json" in the node.js side and made it work, guess i just don't have time to learn, while this fxxking company gave me a tough schedule